# OData Library RTM DateTime Inconsistencies

Tags: datetime, odata

I just upgraded to the RTM version of the OData Library. I've noticed what appear to be inconsistencies in DateTime handling and would like to know if anyone can explain what I might be missing, or if there are in fact some problems. In addition to the RTM library I'm relying on the 3/30/2012 version of MS-ODATA.

MS-ODATA defines dateTimeUriLiteral in the following format (simplified for example):

YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.NS where NS is defined as nanoSeconds=1*7DIGIT

And MS-ODATA defines VJsonDateTime as the dreaded /Date(...)/ format.

However using the Library in verbose JSON serialization we see the dateTimeUriLiteral format, not VJsonDateTime. Furthermore the deserialization accepts only the dateTimeUriLiteral format. This looks like a conflict between the spec and the implementation.

Also, dateTimeUriLiteral makes no allowance for time zone offset (such as would be the case in an ISO 8601 format). However we see that the Library emits a 'Z' terminating character (ISO 8601 for UTC) when the serialized datetime object is designated as DateTimeKind.Utc. This also looks like a conflict between the spec and the implementation.

Also, when we use the Library to deserialize a dateTimeUriLiteral that has the terminating 'Z' - the deserialized object is marked as DateTimeKind.Local. Whether or not there is a spec issue WRT support for the UTC designator, this does not look like it could be correct. Either the 'Z' should cause a deserialization failure or it should result in a time marked as UTC (not local).

Comment: Hi, evoskuil - we posted some prerelease bits on Friday that we believe will help with this issue - would you be able to try them out and provide some feedback on the blog post?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/04/20/wcf-data-services-5-1-0-rc-prerelease.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verbose JSON V3 uses the ISO DateTime format (the same one as XML uses). Verbose JSON V2 and V1 use the /Date(...)/ format. So it depends which version of the payload you're writing and reading.

The dateTimeUriLiteral is not the same thing as the Verbose JSON V3 date time format. The one in Verbose JSON V3 uses the Z (it's literaly the same thing as you get from XmlConvert.ToString(datetime, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind)).

As for reading the "Z" value. This seems to be a bug. The product team is looking into this in more detail. Possible workaround seems to be to either revert back to V2 format, or use DateTimeOffset values instead (which don't have this problem).

Comment: Thanks Vitek. I'm using V3. I haven't found anything in the current spec that states Verbose JSON uses the ISO format (with or without the 'Z' value).

Comment: The specs on the web are probably a little stale. The team is currently working on rewriting them to be more readable and to include all the new features in a easy to consume form. Unfortunately that takes a bit of time to get done. The new specs are published regularly as a work in progress here: https://github.com/OData/v3ProtocolDocument. Feel free to read and if possible send feedback :-)